# Dialog DatePicker problems?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to edit the source code of Dialog DatePicker from this link https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java 
But in line 108 I have to inflate a layout from resource. My question is how can I create this layout. Any suggestions?

Comment: why dont you create a new layout in your layout file named as "date_picker_dialog" ...... and create a date picker dialog with id "datePicker" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 29 you can see

```
import com.android.internal.R;
```

The sample code you are using uses a reference to android internal resources which is, in my humble opinion, a bad idea because it can well change between versions.

Comment: I cannot import com.android.internal.R; in eclipse.